# Creating polygon along highways in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, distance, polygon-creation

In QGIS 3.30.1 I would like to create a polygon that shows an area of 200 meters on each side of a highway. I already have a shapefile of the entire highway network of Germany but they are just lines. I'm trying to use this file and basically convert it into, or add, a polygon with a 200-meter area on each side.

Comment: Please specify which software you are using. Whatever it is, look for the *Buffer* tool or function.

Answer (score 3):

To create a polygon representing a 200-meter area on each side of a highway using QGIS, follow these steps:

1. From the top menu, navigate to "Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer...". This will open the buffer tool.
2. In the buffer tool, select the highway network layer as the "Input layer".
3. Adjust the buffer distance to 200 meters to ensure the polygon extends 200 meters on each side of the highway.
4. Specify the desired output location and filename for the resulting polygon layer.
5. Click "Run" to execute the buffer operation.

By following these steps, you will generate a separate polygon layer representing a 200-meter area on both sides of the Germany highway network.

Note: If meters is not an option under distance, you may have to adjust your CRS